# Android Logs dontpanic

Tags: android, logging

Anyone know what type of information this don't panic logs contain?

```
/data/dontpanic
```

And, how can i analyze this log?

Comment: [this](http://viaforensics.com/android-forensics/android-dont-panic.html) might help. Maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this folder contains some apanic files after a kernel panic happens. For example, if a kernel panic just happens and you go check the folder, you might find these two files:

- apanic_console
- apanic_threads

You can find out in apanic_threads which thread/process is running when the kernel panic happens. In apanic_console you might find out more information such as the stack trace and values of some critical registers: PC, LR, etc. They will help you get your debugging started.